# Create a live edit wordpress site enviroment

Tags: wordpress, web-services

I created a wordpress site that I want to sell. I saw some others sites that have the posibillity to edit their content in a kind of sandbox, with the customizable options. I really don´t know how could I make this. I don´t know how to search for information. If anybody can orient me I will grateful.

Comment: Are you wanting to package a site that has been created and sell it to someone? Have any example sites?

Comment: in themeforest for example. There are a lot of themes that create a kind of sandbox where you can edit the content and modify lyout syles, etc.